# How do older-style meters still in use keep their clocks synced?

Tags: mains, meter, regulations

How accurate must the real time clock of an electricity meter be?

Apologies if this is more a legal question than an electrical one. I am particularly interested in Western Europe but also interested in the question more broadly.

What triggers the question is thinking about peak usage billing. Large power consumers can be charged based on (among other things) peak load. The exact details may vary from place to place but is often the highest average power draw for a 15 minute time window during the billing period. This isn't a rolling window but fixed to the wall clock (i.e. 00:00 - 00:15, 00:15 - 00:30 and so on).

This then leads to requiring the meter to have an accurate idea of the time to be able to correctly bill users. A meter with a shifted clock could come up with values quite different to measurements taken with an accurate one, particularly if peak shaving or similar is in use to try and lower this peak.

I expect modern smart meters with data connections are using NTP or similar and have sub second accuracy. I know some meters used RF signals (MSF, DCF77, WVV et al) and would also be very good. I believe older meters used to use the grid frequency however and this presumably leads to large errors at times (even if correct on average). You can see current "grid time" for the European grid at https://www.swissgrid.ch/en/home/operation/grid-data/current-data.html and historical examples of it being offset by more than two minutes here: https://www.mainsfrequency.com/gridtime.php).

Is it the case that, now days at least, consumers with such time dependent billing all have meters using RF or data to keep clocks in sync? Is there a regulation or standard that covers this? Is it up to each country (in which case can anyone point to some examples)?

Some clarification based on comments so far:

- I appreciate that a clock that has drifted by 2 minutes doesn't change the length of a 15 minute window. The problem, in its most extreme form, is that if you have peak shaving in place using e.g. batteries and a clock that is synced using GPS or NTP etc then it will look at your power usage for e.g. 10:00 - 10:15. It predicts that this 15 minute interval will be a peak so for the last 5 minutes say it discharges the battery. If the meter is running from 09:58 - 10:13 then 2 minutes of that discharge was in the wrong window and there may still be a peak (albeit smaller) and the next 15 minute window may not have needed the power so it was wasted.
- peak/shoulder/off-peak is a bit different because, IIUC, it is normally signalled externally (RF or over the grid) and doesn't actually use the time of day - the operator usually triggers it at about the same time but may shift it by a few minutes depending on how things are looking. Billing then just depends on if the signal has been received or not. No clock on the meter is involved. This question isn't about peak/off-peak but customers (almost always large commercial power users IIUC) that have this 15 minute window factor.
- I feel this must be regulated, regardless of how it is implemented. There is a standard for how accurate scales must be at a green grocer, and how close to a pint a glass must be in a pub and of course how accurate an electricity meter must be in measuring current so unless its set out in every contract, there must be one for how accurate the clocks are?

Comment: I doubt those grid offsets have anywhere near as much of an effect as you might think. A 2-minute time offset does not mean that a 15-minute measurement becomes 13 or 17 minutes. It means that the grid frequency was off by a tiny fraction which, over a period of hours or days, could have added up to a 2-minute offset.

Comment: In the UK, the switchover from day to night rate metering ("white meter" for cheap power at night) is transmitted by a phase modulation added to the Radio 4 Longwave (198 kHz AM, 500kW) transmitter, dating from 1934. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droitwich_Transmitting_Station So this one uses RF, though not as we know it today!

Comment: 1) I know for a fact that 100% electro-mechanical (no electronics) dual-tariff meters exist, I had one in my house a couple of years ago. 2) There **cannot** be a (mechanical) clock inside such a meter as it would **stop** during a power blackout. There was no way to adjust a clock after a power cut as there was no clock inside the device. 3) My **guess** is that some pulse(d) signal is used to switch tariff, to make it completely independent of the meter itself.

Comment: I once was Ops Mgr at Iris Systems in the mid-90's where we invented the best 2 way real-time AMR network . It was compatible with all Electro-mechanical meters.  Time SYnc was controlled by the host in a widely distributed tree on 928MHz ISM channels. It supported multi-tariffs and was sold to Itron after 7 yrs, who was the largest competitor.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. A Sangamo [Q544](https://www.sangamo.co.uk/collections/time-switches/products/q554?variant=41085961286) similar to that used by the Electricity Supply Board in Ireland for day / night meter switchover.*

The specification says:

> Reserve 100hrs (providing battery has been charged for 300 hrs).

and the "Quartz" branding suggests a quartz clock for standby operation. The datasheet quotes 5 minutes per year accuracy.

There's one in my house that was built in 1977. I always assumed that it was running synchronous with the mains with a slight drift possible on backup during power cuts. It seems that I was wrong although it's possible that the quartz signal gets pulled into alignment with the mains frequency. It's running 14 minutes slow! I don't know if it was ever adjusted.

Comment: That's quite cool - but 14 minutes slow would be a killer for 15 minute billing periods! I thought changes from peak to off peak etc are usually signaled via radio or from the grid itself. Its interesting there is a local clock in place instead that can drift 5 mins per year that they leave in place for over 40 years. I guess the meter reader might set the clock each year but otherwise it could be more than 3h off which seems pretty major for any billing.